# Oracle - determine and return the specfic hour of data with the highest sum of the values

Tags: oracle

I think I can do this in a more roundabout way using arrays, scripting, etc...BUT is it possible to sum up (aggregate) all the values for each "hour" of data in a database for a given field?   Basically, I am trying to determine which hour in a day's worth of data had the highest sum...preferably without having to loop through 24 times for each day I want to look at.  For example...let's say I have a table called "table", that contains columns for times and values as the follows:

```
Time   Value 
00:00  1
00:15  1
00:30  2
00:45  2
01:00  1
01:15  1
01:30  1
01:45  1
```

If I summed up by hand, I would get the following

```
Sum for 00 Hour = 6
Sum for 01 Hour = 4
```

So, in this example 00 Hour would be my "largest sum" hour.  I'd like to end up returning simply which hour had the highest sum, and what that value was...the other hours don't matter in this case.

Can this be done all in a single ORACLE query, or does it need to be done outside the query with some scripting and working with the times and values separately?  If not a single, maybe even just grab the sum for each hour, and I can run multiple queries - one for each hour?  Then push each hour to an array, and just use the max of that array? I know there is a SUM() function in oracle, but how to tell it to "sum all the hours and just return the hour with the highest sum" escapes me. Hope all this makes sense. lol

Thanks for any advice to make this easier. :-)

Comment: What do you need to return - just the hour with the max sum, or also the actual sum? And, more importantly - what do you need to return if there is a tie (two different hours are tied for highest sum on that day)? Finally - do you need to run this for one specific day, or do you need a result that, for each day in a given interval (say a month), shows you, for each day, which hour had the highest sum (and perhaps that sum)? All of this can be done easily in a single SQL statement, but you need to give us a very precise statement of your task.

Comment: Ultimately, it would be great to do this for the highest hour for EVERY day, say for the last 7 days. So on day 1, 00 hour had the highest sum of the values, on day 2 14 hour had the highest, and so on. If there is a "tie", whichever hour happened first would be fine...but I doubt that will happen often if ever, as the values are very different and large in the real example (I just used 1's and 2's to simplify this example).

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do what you are looking for:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(time, 1, 2) AS HOUR,
       SUM(amount) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT
FROM test_data
GROUP BY SUBSTR(time, 1, 2)
ORDER BY TOTAL_AMOUNT DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

The query uses the SUM function but grouping by the hour part of your time column.  Then it orders the results by the summed amounts descending, only returning the maximum value.

Here is a DBFiddle showing the query in use ([LINK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d5c2e959c4556ea90d238885f17314e9))

Comment: Any thoughts if my date / time is formatted like this?  

02-OCT-21 12.00.00.000000 AM

I tried to do something like TO_CHAR(dateline, 'HH12 AM') and it does return like 12 PM for example, but it gives me errors when I add in the SUM(amount) part above using "GROUP BY TO_CHAR(dateline, 'HH12 AM')"

Comment: @JF_needs_help I just answered this question for someone else, take a look [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69455944/oracle-query-get-count-of-records-by-hour)